# How to make an ASP application available over an Intranet

Tags: asp.net

I've created a copy of our legacy, (decrepit) homegrown Timesheet ASP application on to a different, newer workstation for backup purposes.

I've finally got it  to the point where I can run it locally over http, using this address:

http://localhost/timesheet/Timesheet.asp

I would like to test it over the network with an address like this:

http://backupServerHostname/timesheet/Timesheet.asp

The live application uses a similar addressing scheme. I'm just not clear on what needs to be done to make this application available from the new server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to ensure that backup server isn't using windows firewall or something to block port 80 access.  Also you may run into permissions issues if your asp app isn't set to allow anonymous access (assuming you want that).

Answer (score 1):

Goto the folder where the Timesheet web stuff lives (could be C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\TimeSheet, just a guess).

Then Right-Click on the folder, select "Properties", then click the "Web Sharing" tab, then select "Share This Folder" option, this should bring up an "Edit Alias" window.  Change the alias to "backupServerHostName".

This is assuming all the machines on on the same LAN.

Comment: Great answer, that's what I needed to do. In addition to checking the firewall

Answer (score 0):

Nothing needs to be done.  If it is serving localhost on Port 80, it should serve other computers on your local network using a name similar to the one you gave.  It may literally be as easy as just trying it...

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to browse to it from other machines at work, just replace the "localhost" part with your machine name.

If you need it accessible over the net, you need to install it with IIS on an outward-facing server, and then browse to it that way.